# Bloomberg APIv3 Get reference data overrides

Tags: python, bloomberg

I have an Excel function that I want to move into Python. The BDP function is:

`=BDP("IBM US Equity","BEST_EBITDA","BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE","1FY")`

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal 
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA")
```

how do I add overrides to this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just passing the override as an additional parameter should work:

```
resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA",
                                        BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE="1FY")
```

Comment: That worked. What about if I wanted `1FY` and `2FY` at the same time? can I do something like `=["1FY","2FY"]`? or do I have to make 2 calls?

Comment: You will need two calls - you can request several tickers and/or fields in one request, but not several overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xbbg` you can just write:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdp("IBM US Equity", "BEST_EBITDA", BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE="1FY")
```